# How to get orders with used coupon in WooCommerce

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

Im trying to get orders in WooCommerce (ideally through wc_get_orders) where the coupon code "some_code" was used.

My try:

```
function get_orders_with_coupon($coupon){
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'limit' => -1,
        'coupon' => $coupon
    ));
    return $customer_orders;
}
```

Only one code is used in Woo orders.

Comment: Hi, a very similar question was asked on Stackoverflow, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769306/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-woocommerce-orders-which-use-a-particular-coupon). Consider checking out the answer to that question!